# C# types quality in 2 assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

I have project A with reference to project COMMON. In project COMMON i have interface T.
I have another DLL B. The B project has reference to project COMMON. COMMON dll is located in both folders.

In project A i load assembly B using Assembly.LoadFromFile. I need to find all types implemented interface T.

```
var types = (from type in assembly.GetExportedTypes() 
where typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(type) select type).ToList();
```

I getting 0-size collection. Also i was check types manually in Quick Watch dialog window like :

```
typeof(T) == assembly.GetExportedTypes()[0].GetInterfaces()[0]
```

and result was FALSE.

Comment: Try reversing `type` and `T` in that LINQ query: `where typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(type)`

Comment: Sure - my error. Stil getting 0-size collection. I think the problem is in COMMON dll library. In A project i have loaded common dll library. When i scan B dll other COMMON dll (same version but in other directory)  is attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i solved my problem.

I removed common.dll from plugin folder and i checked "Copy Local" to false.
I also using autofac in both projects so for this DLL i was made same steps.

Thanks for Your answers.

Answer (score 2):

This expression:

```
X.IsAssignableFrom(Y)
```

basically ask, can you do the equivalent of this:

```
X x = expressionOfTypeY;
```

In your case you're asking this:

```
ClassType x = expressionOfInterfaceType;
```

Which is the wrong way around.

Try this LINQ query instead:

```
where typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(type)
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn´t that be

```
var types = (from type in assembly.GetExportedTypes() 
where typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(type) select type).ToList();
```